# How can I use an admin macro from the command line in wincvs?

Tags: macros, wincvs

I noticed that in the admin tab in wincvs there is a list of admin macros.  One of which lists all of the modules in the repository's "modules" file.

[image]

I would like a way to issue this admin macro command from the command line so I can use this list of modules in a Perl script.

Is there a way to issue an admin macro from the command line?

Comment: Those things aren't part of core CVS. They look like extras in the CVS client you are using (WinCVS).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know there was a difference. Is there any way to do this in wincvs?